# How to programmatically drag and drop element using vanilla js?

Tags: javascript, drag-and-drop

After [failing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75992376/selenium-drag-and-drop-click-and-hold-not-working) to get selenium to drag and drop an element, how can this be done using javascript?

Below is an example of elements that can be reordered using drag and drop, I need the drag and drop part to happen using a js function call and the items to be reordered accordingly.

```js
    function listItemDragged(e) {
      e.target.classList.add("dragging");
      let dropTarget =
        document.elementFromPoint(e.clientX, e.clientY) === null
          ? e.target
          : document.elementFromPoint(e.clientX, e.clientY);

      if (e.target.parentNode === dropTarget.parentNode) {
        dropTarget =
          dropTarget !== e.target.nextSibling ? dropTarget : dropTarget.nextSibling;
        e.target.parentNode.insertBefore(e.target, dropTarget);
      }
    }

    function listItemDropped(e) {
      e.target.classList.remove("dragging");
      e.preventDefault();
    }

    function onLoad() {
      let listItems = document.querySelectorAll(".draggable");
      Array.prototype.map.call(listItems, (option) => {
        option.ondrag = listItemDragged;
        option.ondragend = listItemDropped;
      });
      document.querySelector('.sortable-list').addEventListener("dragover", (e) => e.preventDefault());
    }

    onLoad();
```

```css
    * {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        box-sizing: border-box;
        font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif
    }

    body {
        background-color: #2b3035;
    }

    .draggable {
        display: flex;
        margin-top: 10px;
        padding: 10px 12px;
        border-radius: 5px;
        border: 1px solid #5c636a;
        margin-right: 5px;
        background-color: #212529;
        cursor: grab;
        color: #ffffff;
        touch-action: none
    }

    .dragging {
        cursor: grabbing;
        background: transparent;
        color: transparent;
        border: none;
    }
```

```html
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

    <ul class='sortable-list list-unstyled'>
      <li class='draggable' draggable='true'>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet 1
      </li>
      <li class='draggable' draggable='true'>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet 2
      </li>
      <li class='draggable' draggable='true'>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet 3
      </li>
      <li class='draggable' draggable='true'>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet 4
      </li>
    </ul>
```

The solution suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16848165/programmatically-drag-and-drop-element-onto-another-element) uses `jquery-ui` which for some reason interferes with how the event handling defined above works and sends elements at the wrong coordinates. Is there a way to achieve the same thing using vanilla js?